# how to store data from server in array of arrays and display it in a listview android?

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview

i have searched all over the internet but i am not able to parse my response from server to store values in array of arrays and display it in a listview.

```
{"bannerImages": [
{
  "bannerImage": "dev.beacon.interrait.com/resources/deal-1.jpg",
  "id": 1
} ], "departmentAndCategory": [
{
  "departmentName": "Apparels",
  "departmentDescription": "Apparels",
  "categoryList": [],
  "storeId": null,
  "id": 1
},
{
  "departmentName": "Footwear",
  "departmentDescription": "footwear for men,women and kids",
  "categoryList": [
    {
      "categoryId": 4,
      "departmentId": 10,
      "categoryName": "Footwear",
      "categoryDescription": "Footwear for men,women and kids",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    },
    {
      "categoryId": 2,
      "departmentId": 10,
      "categoryName": "Vehicles",
      "categoryDescription": "Two and Four wheelers",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    }
  ],
  "storeId": null,
  "id": 10
},
{
  "departmentName": "Appliances",
  "departmentDescription": "TV,Washing Machines,Refrigerators etc.",
  "categoryList": [
    {
      "categoryId": 5,
      "departmentId": 11,
      "categoryName": "Appliances",
      "categoryDescription": "Appliances for home like TV,Washing Machines,Refrigerators etc.",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    },
    {
      "categoryId": 1,
      "departmentId": 11,
      "categoryName": "Vehicles",
      "categoryDescription": "Two and Four wheelers",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    },
    {
      "categoryId": 12,
      "departmentId": 11,
      "categoryName": "testing department",
      "categoryDescription": "testing",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    },
    {
      "categoryId": 13,
      "departmentId": 11,
      "categoryName": "2 wheelers",
      "categoryDescription": "2 wheelers",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    }
  ],
  "storeId": null,
  "id": 11
},
{
  "departmentName": "Electronics",
  "departmentDescription": "Mobile Phones,Routers etc.",
  "categoryList": [
    {
      "categoryId": 6,
      "departmentId": 12,
      "categoryName": "Electronics",
      "categoryDescription": "Electrnocs for personal use like Mobile Phones,Routers etc.",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    }
  ],
  "storeId": null,
  "id": 12
},
{
  "departmentName": "Home & Furniture",
  "departmentDescription": "All your Home & Furniture needs",
  "categoryList": [],
  "storeId": null,
  "id": 2
},
{
  "departmentName": "apparels",
  "departmentDescription": "apparels",
  "categoryList": [],
  "storeId": null,
  "id": 15
},
{
  "departmentName": "Levi`s Tshirt",
  "departmentDescription": "Levi`s Tshirt",
  "categoryList": [],
  "storeId": null,
  "id": 16
},
{
  "departmentName": "testing update",
  "departmentDescription": "testing update",
  "categoryList": [],
  "storeId": null,
  "id": 14
}],"productsAndDeals": [
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "A good fabric from levis",
  "productPrice": 2000,
  "productInStock": 7,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "Levis T-shirt",
  "title": "Clothes",
  "id": 1
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "best blue jeans",
  "productPrice": 1000,
  "productInStock": 15,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "skin-fit",
  "title": "Jeans",
  "id": 2
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "",
  "productPrice": 1000,
  "productInStock": 12,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "Aman",
  "title": "Tshirt",
  "id": 6
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product not in stock",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "New T-shirt collection",
  "productPrice": 599,
  "productInStock": 0,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "T-shirts for Men",
  "title": "T-shirts",
  "id": 7
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "askkkdd",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 1,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "abvgc",
  "title": "dddrr",
  "id": 19
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "askkkdd",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 1,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "top",
  "title": "dddrr",
  "id": 20
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "askkkdfffd",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 1,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "topsss",
  "title": "dddrr",
  "id": 21
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "askkkdfffd",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 1,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "topsss",
  "title": "dddrr",
  "id": 22
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "sample",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 10,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "sample",
  "title": "Product",
  "id": 23
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "sample",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 10,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "sample",
  "title": "Product",
  "id": 24
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "sample",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 10,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "sample",
  "title": "Product",
  "id": 25
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "smartphones",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 1,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "mobile",
  "title": "dddrr",
  "id": 30
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "fresh apples from farm",
  "productPrice": 150,
  "productInStock": 90,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "Apples",
  "title": "Red apples",
  "id": 31
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "slippin.jpeg",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "Slip Ons",
  "productPrice": 210,
  "productInStock": 45,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "slippers and jackets",
  "title": "Liberty slippes",
  "id": 110
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "glucone D",
  "productPrice": 60,
  "productInStock": 123,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "glucose",
  "title": "Glucose for health",
  "id": 117
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "new.jpeg",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "rugged jackets",
  "productPrice": 210,
  "productInStock": 45,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "jackets",
  "title": "Liberty slippes",
  "id": 121
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": "--",
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "pens,pencil",
  "productPrice": 10,
  "productInStock": 100,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "Stationary",
  "title": "--",
  "id": 127
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "p.jpeg",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "cricket bats",
  "productPrice": 500,
  "productInStock": 20,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "bat",
  "title": "games for kids",
  "id": 128
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "p.jpeg",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "cricket bats",
  "productPrice": 500,
  "productInStock": 20,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "ball",
  "title": "games for kids",
  "id": 130
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "p.jpeg",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": "a.jpeg",
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "cricket bats",
  "productPrice": 500,
  "productInStock": 20,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "sports",
  "title": "games for kids",
  "id": 131
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "ping.jpeg",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": "newi.jpeg",
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "axe",
  "productPrice": 500,
  "productInStock": 20,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "garden",
  "title": "-",
  "id": 132
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "a.jpg",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": "front_view",
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "--",
  "productPrice": 50,
  "productInStock": 12,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "--",
  "title": "--",
  "id": 133
},
{
  "discountPercentage": null,
  "smallImage": "",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": null,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "best blue jeans",
  "productPrice": 1300,
  "productInStock": 15,
  "totalSaving": null,
  "productName": "bell-bottoms",
  "title": "Jeans",
  "id": 3
},
{
  "discountPercentage": 50,
  "smallImage": "",
  "productPriceAfterDiscount": 550,
  "imageName": null,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "dealResponseVO": null,
  "productDescription": "best blue jeans",
  "productPrice": 1100,
  "productInStock": 15,
  "totalSaving": 550,
  "productName": "curve-jeans",
  "title": "Jeans",
  "id": 4
} ]}
```

This is my json response in this i want to display department name in one listview and by clicking on department name, its respective categories should open in another screen in listview.

Comment: use this site to generate model class: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Use this reference site for more details : http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/

Comment: i am getting my reponse but i want to store department name in an array and by clicking on department name respective category list should be open

Answer (score 1):

Get Your department category in one JSONArray like this

```
JSONArray jaDeptCategory = your_main_obj.get("departmentAndCategory");
```

And then You can use this JSONArray for your List view and display department name bye getting individual obj like this

```
JSONObject joDept = jaDeptCategory.getJSONObject(0)//use for loop for iterate (you can use any loop for iteration eg: while loop)
```

After that you can pass your category list in another activity after clicking listview.

```
JSONArray joCategoryList = joDept.get("categoryList");
```

Pass Your `joCategoryList` in another activity and add that to listview.

Comment: can you please explain it and how to call the respective category array by clicking on the department name?

Comment: Use onItemClickListner You will get position on which your department is being clicked then get joDept = jaDeptCategory.getJSONObject(position) and this will give you respective categoryList